# Sending email through PHP with IF conditions

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email through PHP where the body depends on several if statements.

I understand that you can not call if statements once inside the mail() function, so what I am wondering is if it is possible to declare the body items in a number of variables and then call them into the mail() body.

What I have so far is below, but as I'm sure you can guess, it doesn't work, would really appreciate some feedback.

```
if (!empty($phone)) {$email_phone = echo 'Phone Number: ' $phone \r\n};
        mail('email@domain.com', 'New Visitor Information', "Hello Pastor,\r\n\r\nWe had a new visitor on " . $visit_date . "\r\n\r\nTheir Details:\r\n\r\nName: " . $first_name . " " . $last_name . "\r\n" . $email_phone . " ");
```

Comment: {$email_phone = echo 'Phone Number: ' $phone \r\n}; -- This block looks really strange. Check if that's what you wanted to write.

Comment: To clarify whats needed (appears I have not done a good job of that)

I need the email to only include certain lines if the data for it was submitted in a for, ie i do not want Phone Number: showing if the variable $phone is empty.  I already have the conditions created for which the email should be sent, but the content of it is also under condition as as per my explanation above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    if (!empty($phone)) {$email_phone = "Phone Number: ".$phone; };
            mail('user@domain.com', 'New Visitor Information', "Hello Pastor Steve,\r\n\r\nWe had a new visitor on " . $visit_date . "\r\n\r\nTheir Details:\r\n\r\nName: " . $first_name . " " . $last_name . "\r\n" . $email_phone . " ");

            ?>
```

Comment: This, along with slight amendment going on what Grant put has done it.

Thanks all, can always rely on SO to get me on the right track.

Comment: Please upvote any comments or answers you used so we can benefit from our contribution?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!empty($phone)){

    $email_phone = "Phone Number: " . $phone . "\r\n";
    $email = "email@domain.com";
    $subject = "New Visitor Information";
    $body = "Hello Pastor,\r\n\r\nWe had a new visitor on " . $visit_date . "\r\n\r\nTheir Details:\r\n\r\nName: " . $first_name . " " . $last_name . "\r\n" . $email_phone . ";

    mail($email, $subject, $body)

};
```

This way the mail only gets sent if there is a phone number value.

Answer (score 1):

Build the body first, THEN send it:

```
$body = 'Hello, world';
if ($some_condition) {
   $body .= " blah blah blah";
}
if ($other_condition) {
   $body .= "blah blah blah";
}
mail(....);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it allways like this:

```
$mailTo = "steve@domain.com";
$subject = "New Visitor Information";

$message=array();
$message[] = "Hello Pastor Steve,";
$message[] = "";
$message[] = "We had a new visitor on " . $visit_date;
$message[] = "";
$message[] = "Their Details:";
$message[] = "";
$message[] = "Name: " . $first_name . " " . $last_name;
$message[] = "";

if (!empty($phone)) {
    $message[] = "Phone Number: " . $phone;
}

$message = implode("\r\n", $message);

mail($mailTo, $subject, $message);
```

I use an array to concatinate some strings. This is much faster than concatinating strings with the dot-operator. So it's formatted more clearly so you can spot empty lines more clearly. Now you can see how to use if clauses and variables correcty.

Comment: This way could work, but unfortunately this script has to send 3 different emails, and using that could cause a large amount of repetition which is not necessary, the answer I chose is best for my needs (yes, I understand that I did not mention that in the question, but just clarifying)